# Error in optim: function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

Tags: r, nonlinear-functions, nonlinear-optimization, nlm

So I've run into this weird error in R. I have a simple function which returns an error term when comparing real and simulated prices, called `hestondifferences()`.

when I try to find the local minima via:

```
 res<-optim(fn=hestondifferences, par = c(vT=vT, rho=rho, k=k, sigma=sigma))
```

I get the error message:

> Error in optim(fn = hestondifferences, par = c(vT = vT, rho = rho, k =
>   k,  : function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters

What confuses me is that calling the function directly with the initial parameters `hestondifferences(vT, rho, k, sigma)` returns the correct value.

The function `hestondifferences()` is written in a way that whenever the simulation is impossible for a certain set of parameters, it returns `NA` which is in line with what `optim`() expects.

Comment: Can you show the `hestondifferences` function?

Comment: Damn, just realized my mistake. hestondifferences was expecting four arguments, wheres optim works with just one argument containing a vector.

Comment: @jcfrei you can answer and accept your own answer.

Comment: I've spent 1 hour to figure out optim doesn't deal with NAs. I had some in my data and the function kept telling me it couldn't accept such parameters. I would recommend to be extremely carefull with such values as the error message is misleading

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Optim expects functions to just have one argument. All further arguments should hence be passed in a vector. That is: the function must be **hestondifferences(c(vT, rho, k, sigma))** instead of hestondifferences(vT, rho, k, sigma). See the [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/optim.html):

> fn : 
>   A function to be minimized (or maximized), with first argument the vector of parameters over which minimization is to take place. It should return a scalar result.